# Correlation time series with different length - pairwise or everything?

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, pearson-correlation

i want to analyse the similarity of 3 time series, each with another length. Here is my example dataset:

```
t <- c(2005:2019)
a <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2569, 0.0145896, 0.0369, 0.025986)
b <- c(0.125, 0.04582, 0.2569, 0.256369, 0.25698, 0.1456, 0.0698, 0.369, 1.036, 0.569, 0.256, 0.369, 0.1425, 0.698, 0.105)
c <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2584, 0.05698, 0.1258, 0.2569, 0.098563, 0.1569, 0.123, 0.036, 0.452)

df <- data.frame(t,a,b,c, row.names = 1)
```

For that, I calculated the pearson correlation coefficients with significance with the cor and cor.mtest function and use="pairwise.complete.obs". But this site:[https://bwlewis.github.io/covar/missing.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

say that this can lead to wrong results. Now I'm very unsure, because I'm not yet an expert on statistics. As I understand it, I should take use="everything" with the cor function for the most reliable result possible, but that would mean with my data that only the correlation from 2019 to 2016 is calculated, because it exist just for this period values in all 3 columns?

Does a statistical analysis using correlation make sense, or should it be done purely a visually check of the graphs?